# Pin folders to bottom on descending sort in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am new to ag-grid and trying to achieve a feature for sorting the rows.
I have a list of folders and reports in my grid. I was able to pin the folders on top while using the postsort in ag-grid. This is basically an ascending sort by name and pin the folders on top of the grid.

but now i want to pin the folders to the bottom, when user do the descending sort by name. 
Please help me, how i can achieve this.

Comment: share your code on http://plunk.co. You'll get more chances of getting prompt answer if you have shared your code. Also, go through how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in agGrid **postSort** is there, which gets call after the default sort. Here we can write the logic to extract those nodes and place them wherever we want them to be placed